# div won't fill width with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a 'table' with CSS but I'm having trouble getting some of the `<DIV>`s to fill the width of the layout if the content is too short.

It's difficult to explain in words so here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fatmonk/r2sodp7p/

Basically I don't want to see the pink bit in the example - I want the light blue box to expand to fill the width regardless of how much or how little content is in it.

Using `display: table-row` does the right thing with regards filling the line, but doesn't allow a border to be set.

(The fiddle isn't the whole page - there are more 'rows' to add and the whole 'table' will be repeated with link sand link code and other bits and pieces.)

It's quote possible that in the process of trying to get this working I've over-complicated the HTML as well - I've ended up adding container `<DIV>`s to try to force the width, so it may be that the HTML needs trimming down as well, but I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `width:auto` from the inline style tag of all `.menuContentInPopup` and add `width: 100%` to it in your css, so

```
<div id="poster2" class="menuContentInPopup" style="width: auto;">
```

would become

```
<div id="poster2" class="menuContentInPopup">
```

And the css:

```
.menuContentInPopup{
    display: table;
    height:auto;
    border: 1px solid rgba(99,99,99,.75);
    border-top: none;
    background-color:rgba(235,245,255,1);
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: justify;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here a fiddle showing the result: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2sodp7p/9/).

I have also adjusted the `box-sizing` of all elements so that adding padding to the elements does not make it overflow its parent when width is 100%, this is achieved by

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: The inline `width: auto;` shouldn't have been there.. that was a hang-over from trying to get things working. Your `box-sizing` stuff, however, seems to have me on track... I haven't used that attribute before...

Comment: Great glad it helped, MDN is a great resource for reading up on the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) and the values for the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Values) property

Comment: Next problem is that I now have a `<div>` with some link code in it, but I can't get that `<div>` to limit itself to remain in the layout and show scroll-bars... I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fatmonk/r2sodp7p/12/

Comment: See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Last1Here/r2sodp7p/15/) removed the `display:table` off `.menuContentInPopup` (may effect other uses of `.menuContentInPopup` not entirely sure with just the fiddle) removed `overflow:scroll` from inline css and added `pre` element styles in css, as a side note this should really be a new question.

Comment: Thanks, that's got it again. (I didn't think it was worth posting as a new question as it seemed related to the mucking about I'd been doing trying to solve the other issue. Will consider in the future though, Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

i might understood it wrong but here is how i would fix it.
[Fiddle][1]
I changed the width to 100% so it will fill your full div. Also removed the width: auto in the HTML.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/r2sodp7p/10/
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, another clean solution for your case here:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/giaumn/f99ub6ro/]
```

You just need to care about 2 properties:

> overflow: auto;

on .menu-content and

> float:  left;

on .poster-thumb

Comment: Yup.. that's got it as well.

Answer (score 0):

set your `width:auto;` to `width:100%;` and add `width:100%;` to `menuContentInPopup` class. remove `width:auto` from html inline styles.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqt5ho08/1/)

Comment: Doing this makes the whole table wider than the page... I need everything to stay the same width as the .menuHeader (with it's `width:auto;`)